# Activity over lock screen is not coming for full screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, service

Below is my code in **OnstartCommand** :

```
WindowManager mWindowManager = (WindowManager)getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
View mView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.mylockscreenlayout, null);
final WindowManager.LayoutParams mLayoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON ,
        PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
mWindowManager.addView(mView, mLayoutParams);
```

And added in **Manifest**

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <service android:name=".LockOverlayService" 
             android:enabled="true"
             android:exported="false" 
             android:process=":overlayservice" />
```

In this am not getting the layout over lock screen for full screen by covering the whole display of the mobile,by this the top status bar is visible.Anyone suggest solution to get my activity for full screen covering the whole mobile screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add system visibility to your main view and then add this mView to window manager like:

```
WindowManager mWindowManager = (WindowManager)getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        View mView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.mylockscreenlayout, null);
        final WindowManager.LayoutParams mLayoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON ,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        mView.setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_VISIBLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
        );
        mView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mWindowManager.addView(mView, mLayoutParams);
```

Check this one and let me know is it working or not?

Comment: OMG! this saved my day..scratching my head for past 3 days.. Thank you @ReadyAndroid

Comment: Well, If it's working for you then please accept the answer.